# How to compare date xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to list by using xslt all the movies that has the date bigger than 7 May.Here is what I've tried:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
     <body>
       <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="cinema/movie">
        <xsl:if text="date>7 May">
        <tr>
         <td>
           <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
         </td>
       </tr>
       </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </body>
   </html>
  </xsl:template> 
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

How to resolve this? Thank you.

EDIT

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="movie.css" ?>
    <cinema>
    <movie>
    <title>The hobbit</title>
    <date>9 July</date>
    <duration> 134 minutes</duration>
</movie> 
</cinema>
```

Comment: Please show us an example of the input.

Comment: I edited the question above.

Comment: Is 2 Jan after 28 Dec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 has no concept of dates - and `9 July` is not a date anyway. If you want to compare the given value to May 7 (of *any* year!) try something like:

```
...
<xsl:for-each select="cinema/movie">
    <xsl:variable name="d" select="substring-before(date, ' ')" />  
    <xsl:variable name="mmm" select="substring(substring-after(date, ' '), 1, 3)" />    
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="string-length(substring-before('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', $mmm)) div 3 + 1" />
    <xsl:if test="$m + 0.01 * $d > 5.07">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
...
```

Comment: If using the XSLT in a processor that supports extension functions (like Xalan/default Java implementation) that might actually help. Say, calling a function that takes the date and outputs the milliseconds since epoch. Makes comparing dates easy.

Comment: I was simply adding a remark to your answer to note that if the XSLT is run within a processor that allows for extension functions, those can provide the datetime parsing which XSLT 1.0 lacks. Since it makes assumptions about the environment the asker works in it wasn't useful as an answer in itself.

Comment: I don't know of any extension function that would turn "9 July" or "7 May" into a date - even if you supplied an arbitrary year. As long as you are converting the "dates" to something, it's much simpler to convert them to numbers and compare the results directly.

Comment: The idea was that if the asker needed to do crazy things with funky date formats, they might prefer to do so in a language such as Java or C# rather than XPath functions. They can then write the extension function for themselves. Nothing more than a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, but your answer didn't work. It prints me all the movies

Comment: Indeed it worked. Ty. Also now I want to check if the date is bigger and less that some dates, I don't know why the following code doesn't work, it says that a "(" is missing but I don't know where:  <xsl:if test="($m + 0.01 * $d > 5.07) and ($m _ 0.01 * $d &lt; 12.07)">

Comment: @BogdanTomoiaga You have a `_`  where a `+` should be. No parentheses are required. -- It would be better to define a `dnum` variable as `$m + 0.01 * $d` then test for `$dnum > 5.07 and $dnum &lt; 12.07`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Look, here why it takes also the dates 2 Apr and 8 May? http://xsltransform.net/pPzifqo

Comment: Why shouldn't it? They are both within the range of 5 Jan - 5 Aug.